# Swift not accepting text property?

Tags: function, uitableview, swift, text, return

I am using a UITableView and I am having some problems with the text property. I have declared everything properly and I am sure everything is correct. Here is my code with the error:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Test")
    cell.text = taskAdder.tasks[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
```

The error is on the line:

`cell.text = taskAdder.tasks[indexPath.row].name`

It says:

```
'text' is unavailable: APIs depreciated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift.
```

I am unsure of what this error means or how to fix it.

Any Input and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says there is no text method on "UITableViewCell"

Did you try "cell.textLabel", because textLabel, detailTextLabel are used to set text in UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

cell.text is deprecated since iOS 7.
Use `cell.textLabel.text`

See for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html